# Password cracking program

Tags: python, passwords

I am working on making a password strength testing program that will give ratings based off of how long it took, and how many tries it took crack a password.

I'm looking to crack the input in one of the most simplest ways, starting with one element `[a]` going through all the way to `[z]` and then adding a second element, after which, setting the first element back to `[a]` and the new element would go through `[a]` - `[z]`, the second element would repeat this for every letter the first element becomes. adding a new element for each full rotation of all other elements. until it finds the correct password.

My problem is I can't find a way to start with `[a]-[z]` and then move onto `[a], [a]-[z]; [b], [a]-[z];` etc. While stacking for ever until it finds the correct password. I know that this is an extremely ineffective way of doing this, but I am just trying the basics right now.

This was my go at it. I've tried a few other methods but came up empty handed, so I've resorted to posting it here.

```
usrPassword = str(input('')) 

while ''.join(passCheck) != usrPassword :

    for passwordLength in range(0, 10) : # this loop would be meant to go on forever.

        passCheck.append(' ')

        for i in range(0, passwordLength) :

            if ''.join(passCheck) != usrPassword :

                for j in range(32, 127) :

                    passCheck[i] = chr(j)
                    print(passCheck)
```

Comment: My problem is I can't find a way to start with ```[a]-[z]``` and then move onto ```[a], [a]-[z]; [b], [a]-[z];``` etc. Can you elaborate on this a little more?

Comment: @PyWalker2797 I added another small paragraph, hope it give sufficient context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably not the logic you asked for but I think it is much more efficient as it cracks each letter one at a time:

```
import string

usrPassword = list(input('input password: ')) # List of characters
passCheck = ['a'] * len(usrPassword) # Randomly initialize to some string of same length

print("Start cracking the password: {}".format(passCheck))
allowed_chars = list(string.printable) # All printable characters

while ''.join(passCheck) != ''.join(usrPassword):
    for ind in range(len(usrPassword)):
        match_char = [char for char in allowed_chars if char == usrPassword[ind]][0]
        passCheck[ind] = match_char
        print("Attempt {}/{}: {}".format(ind+1, len(usrPassword), passCheck))

print("User input: {} \nMatched password: {}".format(''.join(usrPassword), ''.join(passCheck)))
```

Currently this works for all printable characters.

**Sample output:**

```
input password: PasswORD-/!=12345
Start cracking the password: ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
Attempt 1/17: ['P', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
Attempt 2/17: ['P', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
Attempt 3/17: ['P', 'a', 's', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
Attempt 4/17: ['P', 'a', 's', 's', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
Attempt 5/17: ['P', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
Attempt 6/17: ['P', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'O', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
Attempt 7/17: ['P', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'O', 'R', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
Attempt 8/17: ['P', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'O', 'R', 'D', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
Attempt 9/17: ['P', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'O', 'R', 'D', '-', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
Attempt 10/17: ['P', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'O', 'R', 'D', '-', '/', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
Attempt 11/17: ['P', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'O', 'R', 'D', '-', '/', '!', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
Attempt 12/17: ['P', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'O', 'R', 'D', '-', '/', '!', '=', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
Attempt 13/17: ['P', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'O', 'R', 'D', '-', '/', '!', '=', '1', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
Attempt 14/17: ['P', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'O', 'R', 'D', '-', '/', '!', '=', '1', '2', 'a', 'a', 'a']
Attempt 15/17: ['P', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'O', 'R', 'D', '-', '/', '!', '=', '1', '2', '3', 'a', 'a']
Attempt 16/17: ['P', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'O', 'R', 'D', '-', '/', '!', '=', '1', '2', '3', '4', 'a']
Attempt 17/17: ['P', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'O', 'R', 'D', '-', '/', '!', '=', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
User input: PasswORD-/!=12345 
Matched password: PasswORD-/!=12345
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

**EDIT:**

If you don't want to use the length of the input password:

```
import string

usrPassword = list(input('input password: ')) # List of characters
passCheck = []

print("Start cracking the password: {}".format(passCheck))
allowed_chars = list(string.printable) # All printable characters

while ''.join(passCheck) != ''.join(usrPassword):
    for ind in range(len(usrPassword)):
        match_char = [char for char in allowed_chars if char == usrPassword[ind]][0]
        passCheck.append(match_char)
        print("Attempt {}/{}: {}".format(ind+1, len(usrPassword), passCheck))

print("User input: {} \nMatched password: {}".format(''.join(usrPassword), ''.join(passCheck)))
```

This produces the same output as above but appends to passCheck rather than using pre-allocation.

**Sample Output:**

```
input password: PassworD-/!=12345
Start cracking the password: []
Attempt 1/17: ['P']
Attempt 2/17: ['P', 'a']
Attempt 3/17: ['P', 'a', 's']
Attempt 4/17: ['P', 'a', 's', 's']
Attempt 5/17: ['P', 'a', 's', 's', 'w']
Attempt 6/17: ['P', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'o']
Attempt 7/17: ['P', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'o', 'r']
Attempt 8/17: ['P', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'D']
Attempt 9/17: ['P', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'D', '-']
Attempt 10/17: ['P', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'D', '-', '/']
Attempt 11/17: ['P', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'D', '-', '/', '!']
Attempt 12/17: ['P', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'D', '-', '/', '!', '=']
Attempt 13/17: ['P', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'D', '-', '/', '!', '=', '1']
Attempt 14/17: ['P', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'D', '-', '/', '!', '=', '1', '2']
Attempt 15/17: ['P', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'D', '-', '/', '!', '=', '1', '2', '3']
Attempt 16/17: ['P', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'D', '-', '/', '!', '=', '1', '2', '3', '4']
Attempt 17/17: ['P', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'D', '-', '/', '!', '=', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
User input: PassworD-/!=12345 
Matched password: PassworD-/!=12345
```

Comment: This does work, but would it be possible to just have it go forever, without knowledge of the length of the password, Even considering if the password where infinite characters long?

Comment: This would also mean not being able to use 'passCheck = ['a'] * len(usrPassword)' considering it requires the length.

Comment: @CanadianCaleb Check my edit in the answer above. I am not sure why you would want to not initialize (as you must know the input password anyways) but I made the necessary adjustments in the code. This will work for any arbitrary length input password, just like the previous version.